# Is that correct to say "an enormous amount of influence/leverage"?

Tags: grammar, articles

I'm really confused to use what before "enormous", my sentence is this:

> X country’s presence in the region had brought it enormous influence not only on allied countries, but even on hostile countries like Y and Z.

When I wrote my sentence for the first time, I had used **"a greet"**
instead of "an enormous amount" but grammarly said that *"I shouldn't
use "a" before great.*" and that's what's confusing to me.

I checked this sentence in grammar checking websites for several times, and every time it gives me a different result. In **"had brought it enormous influence"** part, If I use "an" before enormous grammarly says it's correct, and If I don't use "an" it again says it's correct!

Which one would be true?

> X country’s presence in the region had brought it **an** enormous influence not only on allied countries, but even on hostile countries like Y and Z.

or

> X country’s presence in the region had brought it enormous influence not only on allied countries, but even on hostile countries like Y and Z

It also came to my mind to say :

> X country’s presence in the region had brought it **a great** influence not only on allied countries, but even on hostile countries like Y and Z.

Which of sentences are more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enormous** is an adjective: it modifies and describes a noun.

When you write "an enormous influence" you are modifying the noun "influence" and saying that it is *very large*, which is not quite correct usage. I think of influence as being *strong* or *weak*, not large or small.

What you should do is insert another noun referring to quantity: *an enormous **amount of** influence*. Now you are not describing the physical size of the influence, but instead saying there is a lot of it. This is correct, and what Grammarly was trying to tell you. When you do it this way there is no problem using **great** instead of **enormous**.

Once you have done this you can sometimes remove "an amount of" (including the article!!) and leave only "enormous." You are still modifying the *quantity* rather than the influence itself, but the actual word has been hidden: "...brought it **great** influence" (note no **a** before the adjective). This is a somewhat fancy way of writing and it is fine to not do it this way.

Comment: Thanks, so I can either say **brought it an enormous amount of influence** or **brought it great influence**, right?

Comment: Yes, or the other way; you can use either "enormous" or "great" in either sentence. But you have to have *all* of the phrase "an amount of," or else none of it.